# How to open bootstrap modal form in angular 7 with button name put in input box of form

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular7

I am trying to add a popup screen on a product button in angular 7 and bootstrap modal. when click on product button , name of product shoe in popup form.

Comment: Have you tried something? If so, please include the code

Comment: You can do this using `ng-bootstrap`. follow the given [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for your case :

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

you simply create a template and send it as content to your modal